# Prove that $1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x} < x^2/2$ for $x \in (0, \pi/2)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

How do we prove that 
$$
(2) \,\,\,1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x} < \frac{x^2}{2},\text{  for }x \in (0, \pi/2)
$$
This somehow follows from

(1) $\sin(x) < x < \tan(x)$ which is true for $x \in (0, \pi/2)$

But I don't see how it follows. 
So I know (1) and I want to prove (2).

I think I succeeded to prove that

(3) $1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x} < x^2$

by using (1) and by using the fact that $a^2 < a$ for $a \in (0,1)$

Here is my proof:

$1 - \frac{\sin(x)}{x} < 1 - \cos(x) < 1 - (\cos(x))^2 = (\sin(x))^2 < x^2 $

Is my proof correct? 
Also, how do I get the stronger inequality (2).

Comment: @MartinR By $tg$ I meant $tan$.

Comment: Assume I don't know Taylor yet. I am looking for some more basic proof. Assume all I know is functions and limits. Even continuity is not yet introduced.

Comment: Oh, I think I found the solution !!! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof:

$1 - \frac{\sin(x)}{x} < 1 - \cos(x) = 2 (\sin(\frac{x}{2}))^2 < 2 . \frac{x}{2} . \frac{x}{2}  $

Is this correct? I think that's the trick.

Comment: Try to use \sin x, \cos x, etc.

Comment: @zhw. Yeah, OK, done.

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

$1-\frac {\sin x} x \leq 1-\cos x=2\sin^{2} (\frac  x 2)\leq 2(\frac x 2)^{2}=\frac  {x^{2}} 2$.

Comment: Right, thanks. I just realized this myself.

Answer (score 2):

We can make the inequality slightly stronger. Taylor's theorem for $\sin(x)$ gives you
$$1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\cos(a)\frac{x^2}{6}$$
for some $a\in(0,x)$ and
$$1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\cos(a)\frac{x^2}{6}\leq\frac{x^2}{6} $$
which is in fact true for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.